# EF 3.5 to EF 6 Migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

First off, I need to state that I'm a firmware guy so I apologize for my ignorance on this topic.  I'm likely not providing all the relevant information.  I'm looking for some advice on how to proceed with a problem I'm facing.

I have a project that was written in VS 2008 that targets .NET3.5 and EF 3.5.  There is a database query that seems to be exponentially related to the size of the database table.  It is a read-only query.  I see that new versions of EF have the .AsNoTracking() which appears to drastically improve performance on such queries.

1. Can I achieve the equivalent of .AsNoTracking in EF 3.5 somehow?
2. Should I consider updating the project to EF 6 to gain this new functionality?
3. If upgrading is the appropriate direction, in general how much work is involved?  Or maybe the better question, what changes are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I consider updating the project to EF 6 to gain this new functionality?

Yes.  EF 3.5 is definitely too old, and too bad-to-begin-with to mess with.  You leave it alone, or you move to EF6 (or EF Core).  Note that upgrading EF requires moving to .NET 4, and a newer version of Visual Studio (or perhaps VS Code).

> what changes are necessary [to upgrade]?

Generally, upgrade the project to .NET 4.X using Visual Studio 2017.  Add a *new* EF 6 model to the application using the [Code-First to an Existing Database workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database), making sure to generate the new Entity Types into a different C# namespace.  Then go through the application and change all code that references the 3.5 EF model, to reference the new EF 6 model.  Once you've gotten that working, remove the EF 3.5 model from the application.